# How can I debug an Android app without Eclipse?

Tags: android, debugging, scala

I'm currently developing a Scala application for Android. I probably could get by, with the help of many `println`, but I'm curious if there's a way to debug it with an actual debugger. I am using sbt to build the project, with the [jberkel/android-plugin](https://github.com/jberkel/android-plugin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't necessarily need Eclipse to debug your application
In your `android/tools` directory is a file called `ddms` - if you start it you get a device overview, a log cat screen for debugging and additional information

Comment: But, I cannot find an option of stepping through code, or to set breakpoints.

Comment: for debugging you can use jdb - http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/tooldocs/solaris/jdb.html

Answer (score 3):

You may have more luck with IntelliJ IDEA android plugin (free community version  has android support, but I'm not sure about scala, full version is available for 30 days)